# Windows 7 Rollback basic to professional upgrade

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, license

I recently got a notebook that came with a Windows 7 Basic version pre-installed, and inside the notebook box came a windows 7 professional box.

I installed this professional one over the basic one, by simply entering the new key using the upgrade feature from windows.

I would like to roll back to basic and install this licende on another machine, a desktop, were it would be best used.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can roll back to basic using the recovery discs for your laptop, but the license cannot be used on another PC, it is tied to that hardware for life once installed.

Answer (score 1):

If the license shipped with the laptop, it is an OEM license and it is tied to the laptop.  Installing elsewhere would violate the licenses.